# python 3.5 visual c++ redistributable detecting vcvarsall.bat -license of visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, licensing

I have visual c++ redistributable 2015 installed for python 3.5 but python can not detect vcvarsall.bat should I install visual studio for it?
Can you use visual studio Community to just compile I mean for example if your team is more then 5 people and you create a program with python but you compile it with nuitka that uses visual studio compiler to compile is that legit?

Comment: What are you trying to compile? Python itself, or an extension? But in general yes, you can use the free version of Visual Studio 2015 to compile Python.

Comment: I am just asking about that.did you read my example?(license:In non-enterprise organizations, up to five users can use Visual Studio Community.)

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#compiling-python-on-windows), you need Visual Studio 2015 to build Python 3.5:

> The source tree contains a build solution and project files for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, which is the compiler used to build the official Python releases. These files are in the PCbuild directory.
>
> Check `PCbuild/readme.txt` for general information on the build process.

[The readme](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/PCbuild/readme.txt) tells you this:

> ### Quick Start Guide
>
> 1. Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, any edition.
> 2. Install Subversion, and make sure 'svn.exe' is on your PATH.
> 3. Run "build.bat -e" to build Python in 32-bit Release configuration.
> 4. (Optional, but recommended) Run the test suite with "rt.bat -q".

So yes, you can use *any* version of Visual Studio 2015, including the free version.

This is also further confirmed by the [developer guide](https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows):

> Python 3.5 and later use Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. You can download and use any of the free or paid versions of [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com).

---

When trying to build, note that you need to run the scripts from within the Visual Studio developer command prompt in order to have the proper environment variables set so that all the required files can be found (e.g. the `vcvarsall.bat`).

Comment: So can what my example can you use visual studio community edition to do that because in the license: in non-enterprise organizations, up to five users can use Visual Studio Community? Thank you answering.

Comment: Well, if you just use it to build Python which is then used by other people in your company then I wouldn’t say that the usages of the compiled product count toward the license limitations of VS. So if it’s just you who builds Python, you should still be able to distribute Python in your company (assuming the Python license allows that of course).

Comment: Thank you. Not building python I mean building a software that is created with python with it(for example using nuitka that compiles python to c++) or using it compile some modules of python like for example cx_freeze?

Comment: I’m not a lawyer, but as long as only up to 5 persons do that in your company, you should be fine I guess.

Comment: Thank you anyway for answering.